# Capistrano using wrong release path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, capistrano, capistrano3

My `deploy.rb` file looks like this

```
  SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"

  lock '3.2.1'

  set :application, 'foobar'
  set :scm, :git
  set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxx.git'

  set :deploy_via, "copy"
  set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

  set :assets_roles, [:web]
  set :whenever_roles, [:cron]

  set :format, :pretty

  set :pty, true

  set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')

  set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/assets', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

  set :keep_releases, 5

  set :rvm_type, :user
  set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.3@xxxx'

  set :nvm_type, :user
  set :nvm_node, 'v0.12.4'
  set :nvm_map_bins, %w{node npm}
  set :nvm_roles, [:web]

  set :bundle_path, nil
  set :bundle_binstubs, nil
  set :bundle_flags, '--system'

  namespace :deploy do

    after :restart, :clear_cache do
      on roles(:app) do
        within current_path do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
          end
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

But when I try to do `cap production deploy` I'm getting following error

```
    DEBUG [56b32b4c] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/omega/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/omega/current'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@XX.XX.XXX.X
    DEBUG [56b32b4c] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/xxxx/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/xxxx/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
    DEBUG [56b32b4c]    Directory does not exist '/var/www/xxxx/current'
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@XX.XX.XXX.X: if test ! -d /var/www/xxxx/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/xxxx/current'" 1>&2; false; fi exit status: 1
```

I don't understand what's going wrong with it and I spent quite a lot time already to debug the error but haven't had any success yet.

Comment: You're question is titled: "Capistrano using wrong release path" but it's not clear what path do you expect it to use and why, what's wrong with /var/www/omega/current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that particular scenario was, the `current` symlink was dead. Means to which directory it was pointing that was somehow deleted.

So why Capistrnao commands was causing error `Directory does not exists`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Capistrano will deploy your application to `/var/www/[application_name]` as you have set in `:application`. When you deploy, it looks to see whether `/var/www/omega` exists. It doesn't and thus it fails.

You can override the location to which it is deploying with:

```
set :deploy_to, '/my/deploy/dir'
```